# Data Annotation Validation returns wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

Here is my entire program. I expect it to return `false` but the result is `true`. Do I expect wrong result or I do something wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new Ax(){Id = 1000, Name = "A"};
        //c.Name = null; // when un-comment this, result as expected  
        var context = new ValidationContext(c);
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(c, context, null);

        Console.WriteLine(isValid);
    }


    public class Ax  
    {
        [Range(1,100)] // I expect this to cause failed validation
        public int Id{get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

> Result: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this method:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(Object, ValidationContext, ICollection<ValidationResult>)
```

> This [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411803(v=vs.110).aspx) evaluates each `ValidationAttribute` instance that is
>   attached to the object type. It also checks whether each property that
>   is marked with RequiredAttribute is provided. **It does not recursively
>   validate the property values of the object.**

You should use the other [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `true` as third parameter:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject (Object, 
                             ValidationContext, 
                             ICollection<ValidationResult>, Boolean)
```

Comment: Explain please, don't I want to validate each validation attribute?

Comment: You want. The method that you used, only validates the object, using Attributes above the class. If you want to validate the object using attributes above properties, you should use the other overload.

Comment: Got it - thanks. I have not used it before - rookie mistake